# Can vim mark (highlight) page breaks?

Tags: printing

I'd like to see where page breaks are going to occur when I print (either using `:hardcopy` or `a2ps`).

Is there something analogous to `:set colorcolumn=78` ?

Except that the line count should get reset if a `^L` (formfeed character) is encountered.

Comment: what do you mean with `line count`?. You can of course highlight `^L` using the `matchadd()` family of commands

Comment: Say I determine that 100 lines fit on a printed page, then I'd like every 100th line highlighted. I.e. lines 1, 101, 201, ... . Unless there's a formfeed character, in which case I'd like marks every 100 lines after that character. E.g. 1, 101, 201, (FF in line 245), 346, 446, 546...